# move form into another div with .prependTo

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to move a form element from one to div to a footer div with .prependTo But I am bit uncertain about how to do it.

The normal state is that the form element is in a div called headerRight on the tablet and desktop media queries. For the 480px and below I want to move it to before the current content in the footer div.

I have a sample code I have set up in [jsfidle](http://jsfiddle.net/lupis/818fy8b9/4/). The following is a code snippet:

```
    $("#footer").prependTo("#want to move just the form in headerRight"));
else {
    $("#form").prependTo("#footer")) // or default state in headerRight
```

Comment: your code doesn't make sense. You've an `else` before the last statement without an `if`.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly,

```
$(function () {
  $(window).resize(ChangeDiv);
  $(window).trigger("resize"); // perform the logic onload  
});

function ChangeDiv() {
  var width = $(window).width();
  if (width <= 480) {
      $("#menu").after($("#header"));
      $("#footer").prependTo($("#headerRight form")); // prepend the form
  } else {
      $("#header").after($("#menu"));
      $("#headerRight").prependTo($("#footer form")); // put it back
  }
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/818fy8b9/6/)

Comment: thanks TJ, your code looked lot clearer :)
But something is wrong though, the menu behaves as it should, but the default for the footer is to be at the bottom with its original content only, for all widths except for those below 480px when the form should be prepended to the footer text content, otherwise the from should be back into the headerRight div for all widths above 480px.
When running your code the footer is now part of the headerRight div below 480px and when stretched back above 480px the footer still stays a part of the headerRight